# Files and folders get ftp-ed with 600 and 700 permissions

Tags: ftp, file-permissions

My colleague at work and I both use Macs and use the exact same FTP settings to  upload stuff. Quite often though when she uploads files/and folders they get uploaded with permissions 600 for files and/or 700 for folders. While it should be 644 and 755. As a result those files can't be read and leads to 404 pages. I already asked her to check umask and that is set to standard 0022 so nothing wrong there. What else could cause this? I never have this problem...

Comment: Are you perhaps using FTP as a `sudo` user?

Comment: I very much doubt it. Even I wouldn't know how to do that :) Where / how could I have that checked out?

Comment: Current macOS doesn't have FTP client or server AFAIK.

Comment: We used both Filezilla and Cyberduck for Mac. I never have that problem. With either. My colleague often has this problem with files/folders being uploaded with 600/700. Not always but often. And with both Filezilla and Cyberduck and the exact same sFTP settings